# freeze_authority being null

Tags: spl-token, spl-associated-token-account, freeze-token-account, immutable-owner, decentralization

This isn't a very technical question but more of a theoretical.

I've heard in different places where the in Solana freeze authority violates the idea of immutability or decentralization if an SPL token can be freeze.

But you can make freeze authority **null** which means it gives an option for the Daap to make a given SPL token to be freeze or not. And for me that gives the Daap developer a flexibility rather than Solana being mutable.

Did I get this right ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The freeze authority is unique to each token mint, and if it is set to `None` then it is impossible to ever freeze or thaw a token account. If you want flexibility, you'll want to keep the freeze authority set to something.

More information at https://spl.solana.com/token#freezing-accounts